# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'application' - Pytest

Tags: python, flask, pytest

Im tring to start with Pytest and I need to import my app into the test file

My error is ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'application'

My file tree is as follows:
[filetree](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ygwFS.png)

and i have a wsgi.py file that looks like so

```py
from application import init_app

app = init_app()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run(host='0.0.0.0', debug=True)
```

I have a test file that looks like so:

```py
import pytest
from application import app


@pytest.fixture
def client():
    return app.test_client()


def test_get_assets(client):
    response = client.get('/assets/get')
    assert response.status_code == 200
```

and my __init__ file in my application folder is as follows:

```py
from flask import Flask
from config import Config

from flask_sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy
from flask_marshmallow import Marshmallow
from flask_bcrypt import Bcrypt
from flask_jwt_extended import JWTManager
from flask_migrate import Migrate
from flask_mail import Mail
from flask_cors import CORS

# Global accessible libraries
db = SQLAlchemy()
ma = Marshmallow()
bcrypt = Bcrypt()
JWTManager = JWTManager()
migration = Migrate()
mail = Mail()
cors = CORS()


def init_app():
    app = Flask(__name__, instance_relative_config=False)
    app.config.from_object(Config)
```

Comment: Could you post your error stacktrace

Comment: What command did you use to run the test? Did you run the command in the application root directory?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add an __init__.py file in your tests package/folder. I think pytest still requires it to navigate through python packages.

Answer (score -1):

Where is your file `wsgi.py` located?
Please also provide your exception traceback.
Did you run your test file from the root folder or from `tests/`?

Based on the information you posted, I assume you're having a problem with your import path. When importing with `from application import app` in `test_template.py`, you are trying to import from a parent directory.
A solution to the problem was already posted [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/714063/importing-modules-from-parent-folder/50194143#50194143).